# How to make calculations within a group in SAS?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

For every **PHASE** in every **TYPE** I'm trying to calculate the **AVG** and **STD** based on the last 2 quarters.

**This my current code:**

```
data have;
  infile datalines truncover;
  input type $ quarter phase counter percent;
  datalines;
BB-B 202001 1 94 13
BB-B 202001 2 91 2
BB-B 202001 3 50 2
BB-B 202002 1 79 11
BB-B 202002 2 20 4
BB-B 202002 3 88 4
BB-B 202003 1 17 1
BB-B 202003 2 2 3
BB-B 202003 3 100 3
AA-C 202001 1 67 6
AA-C 202001 2 49 4
AA-C 202001 3 68 4
AA-C 202002 1 23 6
AA-C 202002 2 39 4
AA-C 202003 3 98 4
AA-C 202003 1 7 6
AA-C 202003 2 9 4
AA-C 202003 3 48 4
;
data want;
   set have;
   by  type phase notsorted;
   lcounter=lag(counter);
   if last.phase then do
      avg=mean(lcounter,counter);
      std=std(lcounter,counter);
      output;
   end;
   keep type phase avg std;
run;
```

**This is my current output:**
[image]

**This is my desired output:**

```
type   phase    AVG        SDeviation
BB-B   1        (79+17)/2  (Sdeviation here)
BB-B   2        (20+2)/2   (Sdeviation here)
BB-B   3        (88/100)/2 (Sdeviation here)
AA-C   1        (23+7)/2   (Sdeviation here)
AA-C   2        (39+9)/2   (Sdeviation here)
AA-C   3        (98+48)/2  (Sdeviation here)
```

Comment: Will you have multiple years of data? If so, is there a year column?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the `quarter` descending, within `type` and `phase`, in order to extract the last 2 quarters easily (via a sequence counter).  Not sure about the usefulness of computing std for 2 values.

Example:

```
proc sort data=have;
  by type phase descending quarter;
run;

data have2;
  set have;
  by type phase;
  if first.phase then seq=1; else seq+1;
run;

proc means data=have2 noprint;
  by type phase;
  where seq <= 2;
  output out=want mean(counter)=mean std(counter)=std;
run;
```